# Explaing Javascript eMail Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email

```
(dotsymb<atsymb+2 || dotsymb+2>=e.length)
```

I was wondering if someone would be able to explain to me what is happening in these two instances. Thanks.

Comment: That code is too out of context to be of any value.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Why the atsymb has a +2 and why it should be greater than the dotsymbl. Then what the e(email" length is less than or equal to the dotsymbl +2?

Answer (score 1):

`dotsymb` is less than `atsymb + 2` or `dotsymb + 2` is greater than or equal to the length of array `e`

You will need to provide more information. But I assume that `dotsymb` is the index of your email array at the `.` and `atsymb` is the index of the `@` sign.

Example: `testemail@this.that`

The if statement is verifying that the `@` and `.` symbols form a valid email by their positioning. If the email meets those conditions it looks like it is not a valid email address. (In the conditions the `.` sign would come immediately after the `@` sign OR the dot sign is at the end of the string)